# Retrieving and editing photo 'tags' in Windows 10 UWP app

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to access (and eventually edit) the tags stored on files in Windows to drive some logic within my UWP Windows 10 app.

```
var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Path.ToString());
var imageProperties = await storageFile.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
```

This returns the following:

- Camera Manufacturer
- Camera Model
- DateTaken
- Height / Width
- Keywords (System.__ComObject)
- Lat / Long
- Orientation
- Rating
- People Names (System.__ComObject)

While this is useful it doesn't help. Maybe 'keywords' is the right one but when I look at the image using Windows Explorer properties dialog I see a 'Tags' property and it has a value.

```
var atts = new List<string>();
atts.Add(SystemProperties.Keywords);
atts.Add(SystemProperties.Rating);
atts.Add(SystemProperties.Comment);
var other = await storageFile.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(atts);
```

This is the code I'm using. The problem is this method always return null.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding metatags, it seems that there are often synonyms. Tags and Keywords seem to be used for the same things from what I have seen. I've been researching the same topic recently and am stuck on Keywords. However, I will share some links that I found useful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt244350.aspx
Has UWP code for reading and writing metadata. It is a bit verbose codewise.

I found the next link did things more concisely:

[Exif tags on universal Windows Platform C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088196/exif-tags-on-universal-windows-platform-c-sharp)

Following their pattern I was able to add Author and Title like this:

```
var author = new BitmapTypedValue("Some Author", Windows.Foundation.PropertyType.String);
var title = new BitmapTypedValue("00103 My Company", Windows.Foundation.PropertyType.String);
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, BitmapTypedValue>("System.Author", author));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, BitmapTypedValue>("System.Title", title));
```

It also works for Comment.

This has links to what MS thinks are all the metadata associated with am image.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/ee872003.aspx