# Why do I get an exception trying to add metadata into a GIF image?

Tags: c#, uwp, gif

I'm trying to add additional information into a GIF image in Universal Windows Platform. I thought that I could do it using the Comment Extension block of the GIF format (GIF Standard).

So I followed the instructions in the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj709942(v=win.10), https://stackoverflow.com/a/33093592 and the metadata query I need for the purpose from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/win32/wic/-wic-native-image-format-metadata-queries.

What I've understood is to:

1. obtain the `BitmapEncoder` from a `BitmapDecoder` object of the image
2. make a new `BitmapPropertySet` or a new list of `KeyValuePair<string, BitmapTypedValue>`
3. using the string `"/commentext/TextEntry"` as metadata query
4. call `SetPropertiesAsync` method

I 've came up with the following code:

```
var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForInPlacePropertyEncodingAsync(decoder);

var metadataValue = new BitmapTypedValue("my additional information", PropertyType.String);

var properties = new List<KeyValuePair<string, BitmapTypedValue>>();

properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, BitmapTypedValue>("/commentext/TextEntry", metadataValue));

await encoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(properties);

await encoder.FlushAsync();           
await stream.FlushAsync();
```

The problem is that when SetPropertiesAsync is called, is thrown an exception saying: "Value does not fall within the expected range".
Can someone help me? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please paste the full error message in your question.

Comment: GIF is trouble.  it does seem to be possible, I found all of *one* programmer that pulled it off in [native C++ code](https://github.com/GarethRichards/GifSaver/blob/e4bbb7bc5afcabc66335d0559c8148b569a030f9/GifSaver.cpp#L48).  But nobody that did it in UWP, not encouraging.

Comment: Can you tell us why you need to add this metadata into GIF image and what is your exact goal?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT, I get a stream filled with a GIF image from an InkPresenter. What I wanted was to save it on file with a description.
Anyway, I've solved the problem converting to JPEG. Somehow, the same procedure with the corresponding metadata query for the description field works as expected.